# Django Rest Update

Tags: python, django, rest, service, updatemodel

I am trying to update data via Django Rest PUT method.

```
class TableView(generics.ListAPIView, generics.UpdateAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = TableSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if kwargs.__len__() != 0:
            tableid = kwargs['id']
            mycol = request.DATA['col']
            Table.objects.filter(id=tableid).update(col=mycol)
```

So, this works but data is updated by Table.object which is model. Is there any generic way to update data? I mean, if I PUT col1 and col2 data, it will update them.. If I send only col1, it will update just it..

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use something like this

```
 def update(self, instance,validated_data):





    # The instance is the already saved object
    instance.col=validated_data['col']
    instance.col2=validated_data['col2']
    instance.save()


    return instance
```

check this link for the .update() method   http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Answer (score 0):

This is what PATCH requests does for you. However, in some cases PATCH is not supported (some older versions of Lighttpd for instance) or you might need to use PUT for legacy reasons.

The good thing is that PATCH and PUT requests are almost the same in Django REST Framework. They share most of the code, and the main difference is that PATCH requests sets a parameter `partial` to True.

What you could try to do is, in your `update()` method by manually settings the partial flag and passing it along to your serializer like:

```py
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = True
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
```

This should only update the parts that was passed as arguments in the request.

Normally a PATCH request will call the `perform_update()` function in your ModelViewSet, and just set the partial flag to true and then call the `update()` function after that. Source: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L76

Some info from the Django REST Framework page about the update mixin: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin